# Qual a melhor maneira de um novo sistema se comunicar com um sistema Asp .NET?

Tags: php, asp.net

Tenho um cliente que busca um novo site que se comunica com o banco de dados de um sistema que ele já usa na empresa (implementado em Asp .NET). É importante a integridade dos dados que serão exibidos no site uma vez que se trata de venda de produtos e não podemos vender um produto que não consta mais no estoque. 
Ele fala muito sobre segurança (pois pode ser atacado por concorrentes) mas não sei qual a melhor maneira de atender à demanda. Pensei em um sistema em PHP separado mas que acesse o mesmo banco, mas ainda não sei qual a melhor maneira de fazer isso.

Comment: Esse sistema em ASP possui um webservice para disponibilizar esses dados?

Comment: @AdrianoLuz Não. Mas isso seria providenciado caso optássemos por isso.